# How to add text in PowerPoint using 'officer' package in R when 'ph_with_text' is not available?

Tags: r, powerpoint, officer

I am trying to add text in powerpoint using r by the officer package but the ph_with_text isn't available?

```
library(officer)
packageVersion("officer")
officer::ph_with_text
ph_with_text()
```

Output:

```
> library(officer)

> packageVersion("officer")
[1] ‘0.6.2’

> officer::ph_with_text
Error: 'ph_with_text' is not an exported object from 'namespace:officer'
```

Comment: `ph_with()` https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/officer-for-powerpoint.html#add-content-to-a-slide

Comment: @JonSpring thanks it works, so ph_with_text() no longer exists